# the course in state or props is undefined in react redux app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i have a simple app which have Courses component .in the console.log prints undefined(for both state and props).
the Courses component is as:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { styles } from "../_helpers";
import * as actions from "../_actions";
import EditIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Edit";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import  { useToasts } from "react-toast-notifications";
import { Grid, Paper, TableContainer, Table, TableHead, TableRow, TableCell, TableBody, withStyles, ButtonGroup, Button } from "@material-ui/core";


 export const Courses =(props)=> {

    useEffect(() => {
        actions.fetchAll();
    }, [])//componentDidMount
       console.log(props.course);//course is undefined
    //toast msg.
    const { addToast } = useToasts()

    const onDelete = id => {
        if (window.confirm('Are you sure to delete this record?'))
            props.delete(id,()=>addToast("Deleted successfully", { appearance: 'info' }))
    }
    function handleClick(id) {
         (window.alert('you want to edit?'))
    }




    return (
        <Paper className={styles.paper} elevation={3}>

            <Grid container>
                <Grid item xs={6}>

                    {/* <CourseForm{...({ currentId, setCurrentId })}/> */}

                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <TableContainer>
                        { <Table>
                            <TableHead className={styles.root}>
                                <TableRow>
                                    <TableCell>Title</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>Details</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>Category</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell></TableCell>
                                </TableRow>
                            </TableHead>

                            <TableBody>
                                {

                                props.courseList.map((record, index) => {
                                        return (<TableRow key={index} hover>

                                            <TableCell>{record.courseTitle}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell>{record.details}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell>{record.category}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell>
                                                <ButtonGroup variant="text">
                                                    <Button><EditIcon color="primary"
                                                        onClick={() => handleClick(record.courseId) } /></Button>
                                                    <Button><DeleteIcon color="secondary"
                                                        onClick={() => onDelete(record.courseId)} /></Button>
                                                </ButtonGroup>
                                            </TableCell>
                                        </TableRow>)
                                    })
                                }
                            </TableBody>
                        </Table> }
                    </TableContainer>

                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Paper>
    );

}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    courseList: state.course.list
})




 export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withStyles(styles)(Courses));
```

the courseApi.js is as :

```
import axios from "axios";

const baseUrl = "https://localhost:4000/api/"



 export default {

      course(url = baseUrl + 'courses/') {
        return {
            fetchAll: () => axios.get(url),
            fetchById: id => axios.get(url + id),
            create: newRecord => axios.post(url, newRecord),
            update: (id, updateRecord) => axios.put(url + id, updateRecord),
            delete: id => axios.delete(url + id)
        }
    }
}
```

the courseActions.js is as :

```
import courseApi from "../_services/courseApi";
import { ACTION_TYPES } from '../_constants';


const formateData = data => ({
    ...data,

})

export const fetchAll = () => dispatch => {
      courseApi.course().fetchAll()
        .then(response => {

            dispatch({
                type: ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ALL,
                payload: response.data
            })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

export const create = (data, onSuccess) => dispatch => {
    data = formateData(data)
      courseApi.course().create(data)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: ACTION_TYPES.CREATE,
                payload: res.data
            })
            onSuccess()
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

export const update = (id, data, onSuccess) => dispatch => {
    data = formateData(data)
      courseApi.course().update(id, data)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: ACTION_TYPES.UPDATE,
                payload: { id, ...data }
            })
            onSuccess()
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

export const Delete = (id, onSuccess) => dispatch => {
      courseApi.course().delete(id)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: ACTION_TYPES.DELETE,
                payload: id
            })
            onSuccess()
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

the courseReducer.js is as follows:

```
import { ACTION_TYPES } from '../_constants';
const initialState = {
    list: []
}


export const course = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ALL:
            return {
                ...state,
                list: [...action.payload]
            }

        case ACTION_TYPES.CREATE:
            return {
                ...state,
                list: [...state.list, action.payload]
            }

        case ACTION_TYPES.UPDATE:
            return {
                ...state,
                list: state.list.map(x => x.id == action.payload.id ? action.payload : x)
            }

        case ACTION_TYPES.DELETE:
            return {
                ...state,
                list: state.list.filter(x => x.id != action.payload)
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

the store.js is following:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import rootReducer from '../_reducers';

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();

export const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(
        thunkMiddleware,
        loggerMiddleware
        //window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()

    )

);
```

the folder structure is as follows:
1.courseActions.js is in _actions folder
2. coursApi.js is in _services folder
3.courseReducer.js in _reducers folder
4.store.js is in _helper folder
5. ACTION_TYPES is in _constants folder.
i will be very thankful for kind help.
the error is that state is undefined.

Comment: `import rootReducer from '../_reducers';` What is in the index.js of your _reducers directory? Is the course reduce added to your store?

Comment: yes ,@ageoff course was exported from _reducers from index.js and imported in store.js the content of index.js in _reducers are as :   ' import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import { authentication } from './authentication.reducer';
import { registration } from './registration.reducer';
import { users } from './users.reducer';
import {course} from './courseReducer';
import { alert } from './alert.reducer';

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  authentication,
  registration,
  users,
  alert,
  course,
});

export default rootReducer;'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed the Courses component and used `useSelector()`and `useDispatch()` function instead of connect .this way i was able to access the state.i removed the props argument from functional component Courses .more over removed mapStateToProps and connect completely.i am sharing so that may be helpful for anyone.

```
export const Courses =()=> {
 const course = useSelector(state => state.course);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
 console.log(course);
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(actions.fetchAll());
    }, [])//componentDidMount
//other stuff
```